# Change Password Windows AD C#

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory, passwords, impersonation

Below is the code I am using: I get an access denied even though I am impersonating with an account that is in the Administrators group.

```
SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
string userName, domainName;
// Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the 
// unmanaged LogonUser method. 
// The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.


const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
//This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token. 
const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

// Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token. 
bool returnValue = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle);

if (false == returnValue)
{
    int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
}
using (safeTokenHandle)
{
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{
string x = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username);
up.SetPassword(txtNewChangedPassword.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SetPassword` requires the user your code is running as to be an admin in Active Directory.  Since you already have the old password available, try replacing this line:

```
up.SetPassword(txtNewChangedPassword.Text);
```

With this:

```
up.ChangePassword(password, txtNewChangedPassword.Text);
up.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

What is it with impersonation this week? The `PrincipalContext` object has a constructor that accepts user credentials. All you need to do is:

```
PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password);
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username);
up.SetPassword(txtNewChangedPassword.Text);
```

Comment: I'm still getting "Access Denied"

Comment: Then the user you specified doesn't have permission to change the user's password or the new password doesn't conform to the requirements defined in Active Directory.

Comment: the user does and the password I'm trying to change it to works when I do it through the UI

Comment: It doesn't matter if the user has permission to change the password unless they're also an admin in AD when using `SetPassword`; either use an admin AD account with `SetPassword` or see my answer for an alternative way to change a user's AD password.

Comment: *net user name password*
***DO NOT USE IT!*** It doesn’t change the password, it resets it. When you reset the password this way, all things encrypted with user password are no longer accessible (unless you have the certificate backed up and want to go with manual decryption process). This includes EFS, user specific encrypted app configs, passwords, some Outlook settings etc. https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2020/12/12/changing-user-password-from-command-line-in-windows/

Answer (score 1):

```
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password))
            {
                //PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain, username, password);
                UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(pc);
                up.SetPassword(newPassword);
            }
```